# Convert string to other types (custom) from a vector

Tags: c#, string, vector, streamreader

I'm trying to read a variable from a .txt with a StreamReader. It tells me cannot convert string to ushort. I also need to do it for a customclass.

```
ushort noPhoto;
noPhoto= vectChamps[3].Trim();

PositionHockey lol;
lol = vectChamps[4].Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ushort.Parse()` to make it work:

```
ushort noPhoto;
noPhoto = ushort.Parse(vectChamps[3].Trim());
```

But to `PositionHockey` you have to declare a way to convert `string` to `PositionHockey` instance. Either as a static method within `PositionHockey` class (like `Parse`) or as a [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

**Update**

For `enum` you can use following:

```
PositionHockey lol;
lol = (PositionHockey)int.Parse(vectChamps[4].Trim());
```

if your string contains numeric value of string. If it's string representation, use `Enum.Parse`

```
PositionHockey lol;
lol = (PositionHockey)Enum.Parse(typeof(PositionHockey),vectChamps[4].Trim());
```

Comment: What about the other type ?

Comment: PositionHockey is an enum, can I really create a method in it ?

Comment: @user2180198 `enum` case is a little different. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string into a ushort, like so:

```
ushort number = UInt16.Parse(vectChamps[3].Trim());
```

more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9373sf3(v=vs.110).aspx

For the other type, you can add a string to your objects constructor such as

```
PositionHockey lol = new PositionHockey(vectChamps[4].Trim());
```

or set a specfic field directly:

```
lol.Value = vectChamps[4].Trim();
```

I now see that PostionHockey is an Enum, you can do something like this

```
PostionHockey lol= (PostionHockey) Enum.Parse(typeof(PostionHockey ), vectChamps[4].Trim());
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse(v=vs.110).aspx